# How can I randomly call a method to run in java?

Tags: java, methods, random

I am writing a program that will generate a geometry Logic Word Problem, and I am having trouble with it. My goal is to have the program randomly create a word problem that is pre-designed. So far, the program takes input from the user, and then uses that information in the Story methods, somewhat like a game of Mad Libs. Anyways, I want to randomly chose a Story method to run each time the user starts the program. So far this is what I have:

```
import cs1.Keyboard;
 public class LogicProof {
//Main method
public void main () {
    System.out.println ("Enter 1. to start.");
    System.out.println ("Enter 2. to exit.");
    int choice = Keyboard.readInt();
    if (choice == 1) {          //Take info in and send to createStory

        //Randomly run methods

    }
    if (choice == 2) {
        System.out.println ("\nGoodbye.");
    }
//Create the first story using inputs from main
private void createStory(String adj,String adj2,String adj3,String action) {               

      //Use values from main() to create a problem
}
```

There are two other createStory methods as well. Also, I am going to display the proofs of each problem, and each method has its own proof, so would I be able to then display the proof for the same method, basically just link together the proof method, and story method?

I'm fairly new to Java, and appreciate the help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To only answer your title, you could use random generation with reflection, but that is in no way how you should solve your current problem.

Don't try and randomly invoke methods. Take a look at [java.util.Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)'s `nextInt()` and use that to do unique operations based on the value it returns.

<s>This seems like Homework which is why I'm not giving you a full solution here.</s>

```
public class MadLibs {

    public static final String[] STARTERS = { /* ... */ };
    public static final String[] ENDINGS  = { /* ... */ };

    public static String generate(String ... adjectives) {
        final Random random = new Random();
        final StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder(STARTERS[random.nextInt(STARTERS.length-1)]);

        for (String adjective : adjectives) {
            string.append(adjective);
            string.append(TRANSITIONS[random.nextInt(TRANSITIONS.length - 1)]);
        }

        return string.toString();
    }   

}
```

That's an extremely simple and rough implementation to get you started.

Or maybe, if you have only a few concrete variations:

```
public class MadLibs {

    public static String generate(String ... adjectives) {
        int result = new Random().nextInt(MAX);
        String madLib = null;

        switch (result) {

            case 0:
              // ...
              break;

            case 1:
              // ...
              break;

            default:
              // ...
              break;            

        } 

        return madLib;      
    }    

}
```

Comment: Its actually not homework, it's something I'm trying to put together to give my teacher to use with some of his other students.

Comment: @user1724466 See if the above helps.

Answer (score 1):

Like said above, use random number generation to yourself a 1,2,3,4 ect... Then pass that number into your method as a parameter and then use "if, if else" statements to choose the correct operation to perform. Again, like stated above I will not give any code in case this is indeed a homework problem.

Comment: Okay, I think I may have gotten an idea from what you just said, I will try it, then comeback to reveal my success or failure.Thanks

Comment: I got it, it was a lot easier than I had anticipated, thanks though for leading me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a `Word` or `Phrase` object, populate them into a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

From there us something like [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) or [`Math.random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) to pull a word or phrase from the list

Comment: How? haha sorry, but I'm new to most of this.